# Return with message not show previous data on show blade

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have a problem where when i submit edit and redirect back the show page with message, the previous table not showing.

This is the previous table
[image: Previous table]

This is after submit where only back to the previous page and show message not the details.
[image: After submit]

the page only show the successful message but not the details of the case as the previous case.

This is my feedbackController for show() and update() class

```
public function show(Feedback $feedback){

        $feedback->load('user');
        return view('feedback.show',compact('feedback'));

}

public function update(Request $request, Feedback $feedback){
        $request->validate([
            'status' => 'required|not_in:0',
            'remark' => ['string', 'max:255', 'nullable']
        ]);

        $feedback->fill($request->post())->save();
        return redirect()->back()->with('success','Feedback updated successfully');
}
```

This is my blade file

```
                @if (session('success'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                        {{ session('success') }}
                    </div>
                @else
                        <h2><a href="{{ route('feedback.index') }}" style="color: black"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></a> Case ID - {{ $feedback->id }}</h2>
                        <div class="table-responsive-lg  pt-4">
                            <table class="table table-active table-borderless table-hover" style="width:100%;border-radius: 5px">
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Name</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->user->name }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Title</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->title }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Message</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->details }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Created at</th>
                                    <td>{{ $feedback->created_at }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Reply</th>
                                    <td><a href="mailto:{{ $feedback->user->email }}" class="btn btn-primary" style="color: white">Email</a></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <form action="{{ route('feedback.update',$feedback->id) }}" method="post">
                                        @csrf
                                        @method('PUT')
                                        <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Status</th>
                                        <td>
                                            <select name="status" class="custom-select @error('status') is-invalid @enderror">
                                                <option @if(( old('status') ?? $feedback->status)==NULL)selected
                                                    @endif value="0">Choose...</option>
                                                <option @if(( old('status') ?? $feedback->status)==1)selected
                                                        @endif value="1">Received</option>
                                                <option @if(( old('status') ?? $feedback->status)==2)selected
                                                        @endif value="2">Reply</option>
                                            </select>
                                            @error('status')
                                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                            @enderror
                                        </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%">Remark</th>
                                    <td>
                                        <textarea name="remark" class="form-control @error('remark') is-invalid @enderror" placeholder="Write your remark here" rows="4">{{ old('remark') ?? $feedback->remark }}</textarea>
                                        @error('remark')
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                                </span>
                                        @enderror
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <th scope="col" style="width:10%"></th>
                                    <td style="text-align: right;width:100%">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                                        </form>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

I hope anyone can help me :)

Comment: Can you describe it clearly

Comment: In your blade file data is not visible right? So please share your blade file

Comment: @NimaPatel updated my blade file

Comment: Check my answer please remove else part if you want to show both in that page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your blade file you created session success message in if and html code in else file why?

Please don't use else part if you want to show both blade file and success message.

In your case if success message will come then else part will not show

Answer (score 2):

```
@if (Session::has('success'))
<div class="alert alert-success">
    <ul>
        <li>{{ Session::get('success') }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
@endif
```

Try Accessing like this

Comment: Hi, my questions is the success message is appear but not the table. So, how should i display as the previous page?

Comment: @p1ai This is correct, just maybe needs more explination. Your current implementation shows the success message on success but hides the form due to the `@else` blade directive. So removing the `@else` and doing as suggested here should resolve the issue.

Comment: Oh my God, didn't notice that if else. THANK YOU SO MUCH!